# Why strings does not compare references?

Tags: c#, string, reference, operators

I know it is special case but why == between strings returns if their value equals and not when their reference equals. Does it have something to do with overlloading operators?

Answer (score 21):

The `==` operator is overloaded in `String` to perform value equality instead of reference equality, indeed. The idea is to make strings more friendly to the programmer and to avoid errors that arise when using reference equality to compare them (not too uncommon in Java, especially for beginners).

So far I have never needed to compare strings by reference, to be honest. If you need to do it you can use [`object.ReferenceEquals()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx).

Comment: +1 Exactly. "more friendly to the programmer."  We're not using pointers in C#. We want to be able to write, for example, `if (name == "jim")` rather than `if (name.ValueEquals("jim"))`.

Comment: @Jim: Honestly, I am surprised that this didn't yet catch on as a general language feature: That you would *always* have value equality with `==` while needing a special operator/method for reference equality instead of the other way around. Usually I find myself comparing values more often than references (except in cases where I deal explicitly with references).

Answer (score 7):

Because strings are immutable and the runtime *may* choose to put any two strings with the same content together into the same reference. So reference-comparing strings doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: No, this is wrong. You are probably thinking of Java instead of C#. While the mechanism described by you (string interning) *does* exist in .NET it doesn’t really pertain to the question. The immutability of strings doesn’t a priori answer the question why `operator ==` performs value comparison.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I still hold that reference-comparing doesn't make sense in this case. While it may be not the only reason why the design has been chosen that way, it certainly blows you out of the water when you expect two strings to be reference-different because you initialized them separately but they are the same, because interning occured.

Comment: Well, the runtime thing for instance is wrong. The runtime will *only* do this for string literals. Ever. But more importantly, your “so” is really a non sequitur. The causal correspondence between the first part of your answer and the second that you implied simply does not exist. Furthermore, the onus is on *you* to prove this claim using an official reference, not on me to disprove it.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Editing comments simultaneously leads to awkward "conversations" :-)

Comment: Sorry. After rereading your answer again I changed my comment to make it more precise. I agree that the comments are not the best place for a discussion anyway. ;-)

Comment: I actually want to compare references of strings and didnt know if it would work in my case. Fortunately the msdn docs on Object.ReferenceEquals Method have a section on strings: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx . And in my case, where the strings get read from a file, I should be able to compare references. (My case: I merge (ordered) lists of strings where strings can have identical content, I want to be able to unmerge again later. The order isn't vitally important, but certainly nice to have)

Comment: This answer seems correct to me.  Java does not have operators so devs need to be aware that String == is not reliable because interning.  C# String really is duty-bound to override == because of interning thereby preventing an unreliable ==.  Context dependent == takes some getting used to but its just part of C#.

Comment: If two strings had the same value, and were put into the same reference, then a freakin' reference comparison would be exactly what you want. Ref is equal, then the value is equal.

Answer (score 2):

on a string, == compares by [value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#string-equality)

"Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not references (7.9.7 String equality operators). This makes testing for string equality more intuitive."

In short, == on strings compares the strings by value, not by reference, because the C# specification says it should.

Comment: Link in answer is invalid. Valid link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/equality-operators#string-equality

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From .NET Reflector here is the equality operator overloading of `String` class:

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return Equals(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The equality operators (`==` and `!=`) are defined to compare the *values* of string objects, not references.

There was not any situation in which I had to compare the references but if you want to do so then you can use:

```
object.ReferenceEquals().
```