# String immutability C# (Heap memory, new operator)

Tags: c#, string, heap-memory, immutability

I recently learned about Stack and Heap and I wanted to ask a question concerning it. I've been "experimenting" with strings and I cannot explain - why is the following true if I am creating two different blocks of memory on the heap?

```
        static void Main()
    {
        string test = "yes";
        string secondTest = "yes";
        Console.WriteLine(test == secondTest); //true
        string thirdTest = new string("yes");
        Console.WriteLine(secondTest == thirdTest); //true
    }
```

The first string named `test` is the same as `secondTest`, because they have the same reference value, but when I create the third string `thirdTest` am I not creating a new block of memory on the heap by using "new"?

Why is it still true?

My guess:

What I wrote is exactly the same and I misunderstood the `new` operator, since when I watched tutorials, they were in Java language.

```
String name = "John" 
String aThirdName = new String("John")
System.out.printIn(name == aThirdName); // false
```

This means that what I thought was different

```
(string test = "yes") = (string thirdTest = new string("yes"))
```

is actually the same. (By that I mean that those two lines are analogical)

If my guess is right, how do I create a new memory block on the heap with the same value?
(I want to know, just for learning purposes, I know that it is ineffective for the memory to have a lot of variables that have the same value that are on different memory blocks inside the heap)

Comment: == is overloaded for string class: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,705 It doesn't check references but the content of the string.

Comment: If you instead do `object.ReferenceEquals(secondTest, thirdTest)` it will be false.

Comment: It may also be good to read about string interning - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?view=net-6.0

Comment: String might not be the best thing to learn with, because of interning; pick on some other reference type maybe..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why strings does not compare references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204113/why-strings-does-not-compare-references)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `string` is a bad example since it has the `==` operator overridden and the `equals` method overridden. For string, it is a reference type, but due to many overrides and other behavior it effectively behaves (in most cases) like a value type (especially in regards to equality).

That being said, if you were to create a simple class you'll find your test behaves exactly as you'd expect.

---

Snippets of the overridden equality in String to give you some context.

```
public static bool operator ==(string? a, string? b)
{
    return string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

```
// Determines whether two Strings match.
public static bool Equals(string? a, string? b)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(a,b))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (a is null || b is null || a.Length != b.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return EqualsHelper(a, b);
}
```

It then starts down a rabbit hole of code with `EqualsHelper` that's not worth chasing in here (if you're interested, you can decompile it or find it online).

Answer (score 0):

`string firstTest=new string("test")` and `string secondTest="test"` are the same, second version is just syntactic sugar. About why `firstTest==secondTest //true`, that's why class String override method `Equals` and operator (==) is also overriden and use `Equals`.